# Find element from singled linked list (from tail)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I got a singled linked list.

For example:
52 -> 79 -> 67 -> 50 -> 16 -> 99 -> 75

If I want to get 3th number from reverse order (should be 16), what can I do?
The requirement don't allow me to reverse list.

The only hint is:
There is an algorithm that scan through the linked list only once! One possibilty is to use two pointers scan a list.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

If `k` is the number of the element from the tail, create two pointers: one that point to beginning, the other one to beginning + k. Increase both at the same time. When the 2nd one reaches the end, the first one is at your element.

Comment: your answer is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Using two pointers:

```
Node* kthFromEnd(int k, Node *first) {
  Node *second = first;

  // Advance first k-1 times
  while(first && --k) {
    first = first->next();
  }
  // Now second is k nodes behind first, go to the end
  while(first) {
    first = first->next();
    second = second->next();
  }
  // First is at the end, second is still k nodes behind

  return second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something as the following

```
T *first = 0;
T *last  = head;

size_t i = 0;

while ( i < N && last )
{
   ++i;
   last = last->next;
}

if ( i == N )
{
   first = head;

   while ( tail )
   {
      ++tail;
      ++first;
   }
}

return first;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a [circular array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of size 3 or, more generically, size k (for the kth-last element).

Go through the list and simply add to the array. When you're done, return the next element in the array.

The alternative is the two pointers as suggested in the other answers.

Example input:

```
52 -> 79 -> 67 -> 50 -> 16 -> 99 -> 75
```

The array will look like:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[52, 0, 0]
[52, 79, 0]
[52, 79, 67]
[50, 79, 67]
[50, 16, 67]
[50, 16, 99]
[75, 16, 99]
```

Then return the next element -> `16`.